# chrome.local.storage disappears when clean cookies

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm currently doing an upgrade of my extension (manifest v2 to manifest v3).

I initially used `localStorage`  to saved my data, but since the DOM isn't active in manifest v3 i start using `chrome.local.storage` instead.

The problem i have, it's when i clear my cookies and other stuff, the data in chrome.local.storage seems to disappears, while when I used localStorage it doesn't.

So my question is that, is the chrome.local.storage different, so the disappears problem is "normal" or did i do something wrong in my code ?

However, I have the impression that the extension was working correctly a few days ago, but since then the data has only been erased each time i empty my browser.

So i just want to know if i did something wrong or if my code can't works and i dream about the working correctly...

Comment: `chrome.storage` is not cleared when clearing cookies, at least if you do it inside the browser. Either you've encountered a bug in Chrome or you're using an external program, in which case don't use it.

Comment: Ok thant you @wOxxOm ! And do you know how persistent he is in time ? Same as LocalStorage ? I know he have less storage space but didn't found anything about how persistent he is.

Comment: The storage in extensions doesn't have a time limit. The capacity of chrome.storage.local is the same as localStorage - 5MB by default but can be increased by adding the `unlimitedStorage` permission.